# data-toggle="collapse" inside another data-toggle="collapse" wired behaviour in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have nested element and both consolable, saying the outer element will have class="collapse" to keep it collapse by default but the inner element wont have class="collapse" property.
so the issue is when I am expending the outer element and try to collapse inner element for first time it will collapse and again expand automatically which is a wired behavior but the subsequent collapse and expand operation are normal.
what is the reason?

the code is some how will look like this:

```
        <h1 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#some-id">some heading</h1>
          <outer-element id="some-id" class="collapse">
            <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#some-other-id">someHeading</h3>             
            <div id="some-other-id">
              <!-- Bordered Table -->
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <--!table element -->
              </table>
            </div>
          </<outer-element>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working fine,You missed a class inclusion

**HTML**

```
<h1 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#some-id">some heading</h1>
<outer-element id="some-id" class="collapse">
    <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#some-other-id">someHeading</h3>             
    <div id="some-other-id" class="collapse">
        <!-- Bordered Table -->
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <!--table element -->
        </table>
    </div>
</outer-element>
```

Fiddle[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ntspeun/)

Comment: Kinda good answer, but I need the the reason for the above behavior rather than a solution in form of code, however +1 for your effort :)

Comment: As I also mentioned in my question, I do not want the Inner element to be collapsed initially. just remove class="collapse"   from     <div id="some-other-id" class="collapse">
and you will seee what I am trying to say.